# How to read IP addresses from a .txt file using preg_match in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a ip.txt file which contains

127.0.0.1

I need to get the text file from a form and to display the ping details in the new window using php. how to read ip from a text file so as to ping it from the read information.

Comment: is there anything else in the text file besides IP address? and what have you tried?

Comment: My text file contains only ip address:

127.0.0.1



// I want it to be read by my php code as an IP address

Comment: Look at the php file function to read the file into an array.  There is nothing special about it being an ip address or a special way of storing it.  Now if you want to validate it is an ip that is different.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$ips = array();
$file = @fopen("ip.txt", "r");
if ($file) {
 while (($buffer = fgets($file, 4096)) !== false) {
    $ips[] = $buffer;
 }
 if (!feof($file)) {
    echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
 }
 fclose($file);

 echo '<pre>'; print_r($ips); echo '</pre>';
}
```